# Logical truth question

Tags: predicate-logic, first-order-logic, quantifiers

Is the following a logical truth?

$(\exists x)(\forall y) S(x,y)\Rightarrow (\forall x)(\exists y)S(y,x)$

Intuitively, the sentence seems for me to say: If there is some thing that causes every thing, then for every thing there is something that is the cause of it.

But I'm still not sure if this is a logical truth or not.

Thank!

Comment: Note that the consequent can be written as $\forall y\exists xS(x,y)$. Does this help?

Comment: Hmm I tried to rewrite it in this way but the meaning still sounds the same to me. I know that the different orders of the quantifiers would change the meaning of the sentence, but I'm not sure how to disambiguate this

Comment: Related, possible duplicate: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2150079/existential-universal-vs-universal-existential-quantifiers/2150082#2150082

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes it is!

Your reasoning was very close to a proof already:

Suppose there is something x that stands in some relation R to y. OK, that x is a very special something then: let's call it 'Bob'! Then for every y, is there something x that stands in the relation R to y? Yes, of course, for any y, we can pick Bob!  So yes, for every y, there is something x that stands in the relation R to y.

In general then:

$(\exists x)( \forall y) \phi(x,y) \Rightarrow (\forall y)(\exists x) \phi(x,y)$

And of course you can swap variables, so:

$(\forall y)(\exists x) \phi(x,y) \Leftrightarrow (\forall x)(\exists y) \phi(y,x)$

And thus:

$(\exists x)( \forall y) \phi(x,y) \Rightarrow (\forall x)(\exists y) \phi(y,x)$

Here is a formal proof:

[image]

All check marks, so it *must* be right! :)

Comment: Your explanation is clear to me, thanks!
I have a follow up question: 
(∃x)(∀y)~S(x,y)⇒ ~(∀x)S(x,x) is also a logical truth, right?
Since the universal quantifies over y in the antecedent, we can simply replace y with x to get the consequence.

Comment: @stardust Correct! Yes, that is also a logical consequence: if there is something that does not stand in relation S to anything, then that somethng does not stand in relation S to itself, and hence it is not true that everything stands in relation S to itself.